# How can I create a launcher Icon for my qt project? (kubuntu)

Tags: qt

I'd like to create an icon for my applications launcher the project is for my own use and will be running on Kubuntu, where about's would I make the change I'm guessing the .pro and if so how would I go about making said change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have a Qt guide on how to perform the change you want to: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html (Setting the Application Icon on Common Linux Desktops). Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I came across this I guess I just misunderstood it initially thanks :)